# Can thrift server side detect "invalid method name" calling?

Tags: java, thrift

The question is, the thrift client side throws exception: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'xxxNotMyMethod', while the server side cannot detect what is happening.

Is there a way to logging this situation on server just like "HTTP 404 Not Found" on Nginx's error.log?

Answer (score 1):

No, since [inside the `process()` method](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/TBaseProcessor.java#L26) the method names are just looked up against a compiler-generated key-value dictionary or map to find the implementation. If that fails, the code throws an `TApplicationException`.

If you have the chance to wrap the processor call (e.g. override `process()`) into some other code, then you could theoretically catch that exception and do some additional things.